# Where can I find and download the Java Speech API?

Tags: java, speech-recognition

Could you please tell me from where I can download JVM 1.4 and the Java Speech API?

#### See also:

> [Download and install IBM’s Speech for Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/783067/download-and-install-ibms-speech-for-java)

Comment: I do not believe the linked question is a duplicate. IBM's Speech for Java is only one implementation of the Speech API, and it is no longer available. This is a more general (and useful!) question.

Answer (score 5):

A link from the [Desktop Java Java Speech API](https://web.archive.org/web/20090227082336/http://java.sun.com/products/java-media/speech/) leads to the SourceForge page for [FreeTTS](http://freetts.sourceforge.net/docs/index.php).  The [FAQ says](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/jsapifaq-135248.html):

> The Java Speech API (JSAPI) is not part of the JDK and Sun does not ship an
>   implementation of JSAPI. Instead, we work with third party speech companies to
>   encourage the availability of multiple implementations.

The [FAQ](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/jsapifaq-135248.html#implementation) also lists and links to several more implementations:

- [FreeTTS](http://freetts.sourceforge.net/)
- [The Cloud Garden](https://web.archive.org/web/20090610064142/http://cloudgarden.com/)
- [Lernout & Hauspie's TTS for Java Speech API](http://www.lhs.com/) (link redirects to http://www.nuance.com/, so the application may or may not still be available)
- [Conversa Web 3.0](http://www.conversa.com/) (link now goes to a Spanish immersion training company)
- [Festival](http://www.cstr.ed.ac.uk/projects/festival/)
- [Elan Speech Cube](http://www.elantts.com/products/fp_speechcube.html) (link gets an HTTP 404 error)

I haven't investigated any of these myself, but there appears to be a wealth of 3rd party implementations.

Comment: The FAQ is out of date.  L&H, Convera, and Elan Speech Cube no longer appear to be around.

Answer (score 1):

http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/download.html