# AJAX Chat How to add voice with Java?

Tags: java, web, voice

Ok so I use Ajax Chat (http://sourceforge.net/projects/ajax-chat/) and it is a great chat script. I use the MyBB Integrated version and all is well. What I am wanting to know is how I could add voice capabilities.

Basically each channel would be similar to a Yahoo chat room and have a talk button. This way someone could talk and the rest of the room could hear.

Flash is NOT an option, and I tried RED5 with it and the results were terrible. Bad quality, couldnt hear half of the time, etc.

I have searched and searched and searched and all I find is calling, IP-to-IP, etc.

I would like to do this in JAVA if possible which is not one of my best languages. I do have root access to my server and it is linux (CentOS). So what I really need is a point in the right direction on how to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is to use the Java Speech API. You can find out more information about this at this [site](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/jsapifaq-135248.html). This question was already answered actually in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/787462/where-can-i-find-and-download-the-java-speech-api).